# Probability theory in sympy.stats

Tags: python, sympy, probability

This code should output 2/6 but I just get 0

```
from sympy.stats import Die, P, Normal

n = 6

X = Die('X', n) # Six sided Die

P(X == 1) + P(X == 5)
```

Even when I just try to calculate the probability of the die landing on a specific number like P(X==1), it outputs 0!

Answer (score 6):

`Die` doesn't implement equals in the way you are expecting it to. If you just write `X == 1` the result is `False`. However, if you write something like `X > 3` you do not get `True` or `False`, you get an expression (meaning `P` can hope to return something from it).

When you write

```
P(X == 1)
```

That is identical to writing

```
P(False)
```

which is meaningless for a die. If you want the probabilities of each face, you can use `density`:

```
from sympy.stats import Die, P, Normal, density
n = 6
X = Die('X', n) # Six sided Die
density(X)[1] + density(X)[5] # 1/3
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Eq(x,y)` from `sympy` itself:

```
from sympy.stats import Die, P, Normal
from sympy import Eq

n = 6
X = Die('X', n) # Six sided Die

print(P(Eq(X, 1)) + P(Eq(X, 5))) # prints 1/3
```